# Where are valid values defined for @Scope in web-aware and portal spring contexts?

Tags: java, annotations, scope, spring-3

The following allows the declaration of a singleton bean in Spring 3.0:

```
@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
private void setBean1(Bean1 b1) {
    this.b1 = b1;
}
```

But, `BeanDefinition` does not define scopes values for request, session and global session. Where are these defined? Else, should I use `@Scope("request")`, `@Scope("session")` and `@Scope("global session")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use string literals if you want (though global session would be "globalSession").

Alternatively, you can use constants defined in [`WebApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html).

Answer (score 9):

`BeanDefinition` only has `SCOPE_SINGLETON` and `SCOPE_PROTOTYPE`.

The other scopes, being only applicable to web applications, are defined in `org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext`.

A useful list of constants can be found in the javadoc for [Constant Field values](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/constant-values.html#org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON).

Answer (score 3):

There is no single place, where all the scope names are defined, and not all scope names have constants:

- singleton   -> ConfigurableBeanFactory#SCOPE_SINGLETON
- prototype   -> ConfigurableBeanFactory#SCOPE_PROTOTYPE
- request     -> WebApplicationContext#SCOPE_REQUEST
- session     -> WebApplicationContext#SCOPE_SESSION
- application -> WebApplicationContext#SCOPE_APPLICATION
- websocket   -> not defined (at lease I did not find)